# Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.1 - possible to change format of exported report?

Tags: export-to-excel

Is it possible to change the format of a Jaspersoft report when the operator is requesting an export?
My customer wants the report heading removed if he is exporting the report to a XLSX file.

I thought of several options: clearing the text field that contains the heading; deleting the page header section, etc but they all require detecting that an export is being done.  Are there any builtin functions that do that?

Or is there a way to specify that one format is used for display and another format is used for export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer from the Jaspersoft community

```html
To remove header on export:
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
To remove footer on export:
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
```